# Sending multiple files from C# to C

Tags: c#, c, wpf, file

I have a wpf gui that I want to upload files from and send to a C client .
I want to send 3 files and for some reason 1 of them is being sent and written (but it adds 8 nulls in the end and removes 4 of the first letters in the file)
and in the other two when I try to receive the size it says their size is 0
I've been stuck on this problem for a while now and  i'm becoming depserate as i'm probably missing a small thing , if any of u could give a hand that'll mean a lot ! I really wanna know whats the problem in my code.

I have the files paths in an array and sending it in main like so

**C# Main**

```cs
IPEndPoint ipPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 5555);//switch the port
Socket listenSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
listenSocket.Bind(ipPoint);
listenSocket.Listen(1);

Socket clientSocket = listenSocket.Accept();
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
    SendFile(clientSocket, filePaths[i]);
}
clientSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
clientSocket.Close();
```

**SendFile(C# side)**

```cs
public static void SendFile(Socket clientSocket, string filePath)
{
    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filePath);
        long file_size = fi.Length;
        byte[] preBuffer;
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream))
            {
                writer.Write(file_size);
            }

            preBuffer = memoryStream.ToArray();
            byte[] fixedBuffer = new byte[4];
            Array.Copy(preBuffer, 0, fixedBuffer, 0, 4);
            Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(preBuffer));
            Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(fixedBuffer)); //fixing the problem i had with the converting to array that it added 4 useless zeros.
            clientSocket.Send(fixedBuffer); // sending size

        }
        byte[] data = new Byte[4096];

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            int actualRead;
            do
            {
                actualRead = fs.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                clientSocket.Send(data);
                file_size -= actualRead;
            } while (file_size - filePath.Length > 0);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("File for the program is missing! lua/pcap/csv");
    }
}
```

**C Receive(built from 3 functions)**

```c
/*
============================================
General : function is responsible for receiving a length of data from the client
Parameters : sock - client socket to receive the data from
             *buf - holds a pointer to the buffer that needs to update
             bufsize - the length of the buffer
Return Value : returns TRUE when the data is read correctly
               else, FALSE when there was a socket error or no bytes are received.
============================================
*/
bool recv_raw(SOCKET sock, void* buf, int bufsize)
{
    unsigned char* pbuf = (unsigned char*)buf;
    while (bufsize > 0) {
        int num = recv(sock, pbuf, bufsize, 0);
        if (num <= 0) { return false; }
        pbuf += num;
        bufsize -= num;
    }
    return true;
}

/*
===================================================
General : receives the length of the file and updates it

Parameters : sock - client socket to receive the data from
             *filesize - holds a pointer to the size of the buffer that needs to update
             filesize_len - the length of the file size pointer
Return Value : returns TRUE when the size is read correctly
               else, FALSE when there was a socket error or no bytes are received.
===================================================
*/
bool recv_file_len(SOCKET sock, long* filesize)
{
    if (!recv_raw(sock, filesize, sizeof(*filesize))) { return false; }
    return true;
}

/*
================================================== =
General : writes to the lua file the data from the file
    that was received in the socket
    Parameters : sock - the socket between the client and server
    *f - the file to write the data received to
    Return Value : returns TRUE when everything was written to the file.
    returns FALSE if there's no data received or detected a socket problem.
    ================================================== =
    */
bool write_data(SOCKET sock, FILE *f)
{
    long filesize;//size of address
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    if (!recv_file_len(sock, &filesize)) { return false; }
    printf("file size (From C#) : %ld\n", filesize);
    int n = recv_raw(sock, buffer, 8); // need to get the size of the name
    if (filesize > 0)
    {
        do {
            int num = min(filesize, BUFFER_SIZE);
            if (!recv_raw(sock, buffer, num)) {
                return false;
            }
            int offset = 0;
            do
            {
                size_t written = fwrite(&buffer[offset], 1, num - offset, f);
                if (written < 1) { return false; }
                offset += written;
            } while (offset < num);
            filesize -= num;
        } while (filesize > 0);
    }
    return true;
}
```

**C Main**

```c
FILE* luafhandler = fopen("test.lua", "wb");//the new lua file
if (luafhandler == NULL)
{
    fclose(luafhandler);
    printf("GUI CONNECT lua file failed to open!\n");
}
FILE* pcapfhandler = fopen("test.pcap", "wb");//the new lua file
if (pcapfhandler == NULL)
{
    fclose(pcapfhandler);
    printf("GUI CONNECT pcap file failed to open!\n");
}
FILE* csvfhandler = fopen("AlgoTest.csv", "wb");//the new lua file
if (csvfhandler == NULL)
{
    fclose(csvfhandler);
    printf("GUI CONNECT csv file failed to open!\n");
}
else {
    SOCKET sock1 = open_socket(5555, SERVER_IP);
    bool check = write_data(sock1, luafhandler);
    bool check1 = write_data(sock1, pcapfhandler);
    bool check2 = write_data(sock1, csvfhandler);

    fclose(luafhandler);
    fclose(pcapfhandler);
    fclose(csvfhandler);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the end of your file send loop be "} while (file_size  > 0);"? You initialize file_size with the number of bytes in the file and then in your loop knock off the number of bytes actually sent. Also, and this is probably a bit pernickety, but consider putting the while at the top of the loop instead of the bottom. Then it should cope with 0 byte files. Anyway, try that and see if you benefit.

Comment: Your file length is a long (8 bytes) but you are sending (4 bytes).

Comment: the four bytes in the beginning are most likely the magic number of the file.
check this out:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures and
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#In_files